# Which driver is compatible with my hardware?

Tags: drivers, graphics, overheating, amd-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.4 LTS. I consider my netbook specs as low, yet modern. I bought it in 2014. However, the frequent overheat is bugging me.

I googled and found that my processor is originally designed to be used in a tablet, but for-some-reasons-that-I-don't-know-why HP is using it for a netbook. Does this have anything to do with the issue? Based on the result of my googling and browsing, I keep being informed that such an issue happening due to the relation of CPU and the graphic card and its provided drivers.

Here is the info of the hardware you might require to know:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8180]
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 22a2
  Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Is it because the hardware has no fan, just 3 small vents?
If that's the case, why is it more overheated than when it was running Windows 7 Home?

Last but not least, my main question is: which driver should I pick to reduce the overheat? The proprietary, the open-source, or the open-source (updates)?
That netbook is currently running on the proprietary one (using Catalyst)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Hi Karl, thx for the very fast response.

Comment: I did what suggested and it went like this: 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8180]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 22a2
 Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

Comment: I believe the proprietary drivers give better temperature especially on gaming. But I guess the best way to find out, is to try it yourself. Install the proprietary drivers and check the temperatures (psensor is a good program for temperature measurements). Then let us know your findings :P

Comment: besides the driver issue, I would recomment you to use a more lightweight flavour of Ubuntu. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) are good options.